# C# Basic OOP - Making a Dictionary of a Class with Constructors

Tags: c#, list, class, oop, dictionary

The code I've been trying and what went wrong: http://ideone.com/cvLRLg

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Minion
    {
        public static int manaCost;
        public static int attack;
        public static int health;
        public static string cardText;
        public Minion(int mana, int atk, int h, string txt)
        {
            manaCost = mana;
            attack = atk;
            health = h;
            cardText = txt;
        }
        public void displayStats(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "\nMana Cost: " + manaCost + "\nAttack: " + attack + "\nHealth: " + health + "\n" + cardText + "\n");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> indexList = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, Minion> minionList = new Dictionary<string, Minion>();

            //buffer so I start at 1 and not 0
            indexList.Add("MissingNo");

            //make a Wolfrider card
            indexList.Add("Wolfrider");
            Minion Wolfrider = new Minion(3, 3, 1, "Charge");
            minionList.Add(indexList[1], Wolfrider);

            //make a Goldshire Footman card
            indexList.Add("Goldshire Footman");
            Minion GoldshireFootman = new Minion(1, 1, 2, "Taunt");
            minionList.Add(indexList[2], GoldshireFootman);

            //look through all my cards
            for (int i = 1; i < indexList.Count(); i++)
                minionList[indexList[i]].displayStats(indexList[i]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying to teach myself C# but this has been stumping me.  I want to make a Dictionary that accepts a string then returns a Minion (the new class).

A Minion accepts four arguments when it's made so I had to dedicate a line of code to making a new Minion BEFORE adding that to the Dictionary.

However, when I'm going through all the Minions that I have, for some reason the first one is giving me back the properties of the OTHER Minion.

```
Wolfrider
Mana Cost: 1
Attack: 1
Health: 2
Taunt

Goldshire Footman
Mana Cost: 1
Attack: 1
Health: 2
Taunt
```

The List is working properly because the names are correct... but the Wolfrider has the properties of the Goldshire Footman.

Is there a more efficient/optimized way to do this?  If not, what have I been doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is that your members are [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx):

```
public static int manaCost
```

So basically, the last value you affect wins. Transform them into *instance properties*:

```
public int ManaCost { get; set; }
```

Then get rid of `indexList` and directly use your Minion's name as the dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

Well remove keyword `static` from all your class members. You don't want for all minions to have same values don't you ?

You can also add field or property `name` to your class :

```
  public class Minion
    {
        public readonly string name;
        public int manaCost;
        public int attack;
        public int health;
        public string cardText;

        public Minion(string name, int mana, int atk, int h, string txt)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.manaCost = mana;
            this.attack = atk;
            this.health = h;
            this.cardText = txt;
        }
        public void displayStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + "\nMana Cost: " + manaCost + "\nAttack: " + attack + "\nHealth: " + health + "\n" + cardText + "\n");
        }
    }
```

In your `Main` method you don't really need this `List<string>` to work with your dictionary. You can remove it and change your code to :

```
        Dictionary<string, Minion> minionList = new Dictionary<string, Minion>();

        Minion Wolfrider = new Minion("Wolfrider", 3, 3, 1, "Charge");
        minionList.Add(Wolfrider.name , Wolfrider);

        //make a Goldshire Footman card
        Minion GoldshireFootman = new Minion("Goldshire", 1, 1, 2, "Taunt");
        minionList.Add(GoldshireFootman.name, GoldshireFootman);

        foreach(Minion minion in minionList.Values)
          minion.DisplayStats();

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ah, the foreach loop, thanks!  Is there a way I can access the "key" for each element?  If I use a foreach,  is there a way for me to get the card name (the string inputted to access that minion)

Comment: Using the following:  

foreach(Minion min in minionList)
                min.displayStats();  

Resulted in an error: Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,ConsoleApplication1.Minion>' to 'ConsoleApplication1.Minion'  

I'm sorry I have no idea how to format this comment.

Comment: @CiscoOrtega It is actually `foreach(Minion minion in minionList.Values)` (i updated my answer, check it please)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have static members for your class. Remove the static in the below.

```
public static int manaCost;
public static int attack;
public static int health;
public static string cardText;
```

Here is a slightly cleaner version of what you may be aiming for:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace ConsoleApplication3
    {
        public class Minion
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public int manaCost { get; set; }
            public int attack { get; set; }
            public int health { get; set; }
            public string cardText { get; set; }

            public void displayStats()
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name + "\nMana Cost: " + manaCost + "\nAttack: " + attack + "\nHealth: " + health + "\n" + cardText + "\n");
            }

            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    var minionList = new List<Minion>();

                    minionList.Add(new Minion() { name = "Wolfrider", attack = 3, cardText = "Charge", health = 3, manaCost = 3 });
                    minionList.Add(new Minion() { name = "GoldShire Footman", attack = 1, cardText = "Taunt", health = 1, manaCost = 2 });

                    //look through all my cards
                    foreach (var minion in minionList)
                        minion.displayStats();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```